# Max product subarray with all real positive number

Tags: python, arrays

Given an array X of n positive real numbers , I have to find a subarray X[i,j] , that starts with X[i] and finishes with X[j] , that maximizes the product of all the numbers in this subArray

Comment: What about `[x for x in [1,3,7,0.3,4,0.2,1,5] if x > 1.0]` ?

Comment: You might want to tell the whole requirement/assignment. If you just want a subset of numbers that have the greatest product, you obviously just remove all numbers that are smaller than 1.

Comment: This may help you : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-product-subarray/

Comment: @JJJ , it's subarray not the subset.

Comment: Where is python in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 from functools import reduce
 from operator import mul
 from scipy import stats
```

and generate a Test Array like this:

```
 X = stats.randint(-10,10).rvs(100)
```

Then you can calculate the Subsequence with the maximal product like this:

```
 > max([(reduce(mul, X[i:j], 1), i,j) 
         for i in range(X.size) for j in range(i,X.size)])
 (2140585984, 32, 66)
```

This means, that the Subsequence X[32:66] has the maximum product. (But beware of overflow: The numpy-Datatypes have restricted memory space).